# Converting program to use objects instead of numbers

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am asked to convert a program to use generic types in my array.

I have no idea where to start. I tried to convert the array to generic but I keep getting problems.

I tried to just convert the array to generic one by using `queArray = (T[]) (new Comparable[maxSize]);` but after I modified all variables to suppose to use generic types I keep getting errors.

What do I have to change here?

Comment: The purpose of generics is to avoid casting like (Long) and that's what your doing.

Comment: It's exactly what the error says - you're trying to cast an `Integer`  to a `Long` ... you can't do that. Why are you trying to cast it? You're also not passing a type when instantiating your (Generic) `PriorityQ<T>`

Comment: @Brian Roach, I'm trying to ca st it because I need to compare values and when not casting, I get error saying something like cannot compare T, T.

Comment: Check Tim's answer below - that's because you're using generics. Your type `T` needs to be constrained to something that is comparable via an interface. All the `Number` subclasses (`Long`, `Integer`, etc) implement `Comparable<T>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to declare that `T` must implement `Comparable`. This allows you to explicitly state that the `PriorityQ` can only support classes which can be compared for ordering. This is done like so:

```
class PriorityQ<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

Now `queArray` should be `new`ed as an array of `T` since the `PriorityQ` is ordering instances of type `T`:

```
queArray = new T[maxSize];
```

Lastly, use the `Comparable.compareTo` method for your comparisons:

```
if( item .compareTo(queArray[j]) > 0 )      // if new item larger,
```

Comment: Ok, this actually made my code compile this time :) I just should add that also the input must be converted to Long as well by using `thePQ.insert(Long.valueOf(30));`. I think your answer answers my question.

Comment: @NewHelpNeeder - You can use that method or just pass `30L`. The autoboxing will convert it to a `Long` object.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you want, but I'll take a guess...

Put a bound on your type (edited - was `<T extends Number>`, but `Number` doesn't implement `Comparable`):

```
class PriorityQ<T extends Number & Comparable<T>>
```

Change your methods to return `T`, eg:

```
public T peekMin()
```

Then for the `Long` implementation, just:

```
PriorityQ<Long> pqLong = new PriorityQ<Long>(9);
```

Comment: The question asks specifically to use `Object` and not `Number`

Comment: I wish I could -1 you. you've misunderstood the question. It says don't use number (lowercase) not Number - he means primitives. And Number *is* an Object.

Comment: Bohemian is right. I need to change input from being just integer number to an object.

Comment: meh, I think that's mincing words. Since two rep upsets you so much, I'll remove the downvote. There is no such thing as primitives with auto-boxing. Everything is an object. Technically `Number` is a class, but using that is not as flexible ... look at `PriorityQueue`

Comment: `T extends Number` doesn't actually help as the `Number` parent class doesn't define the comparison methods. You have no guarantee that a subclass of `Number` provides a method for comparison. All the core subclasses happen to do so (by implementing `Comparison<T>`) ... but you aren't guaranteed that. Tim is correct.

Comment: In my situation, `<T extends Comparable<T>>` is what does the job.

Comment: @BrianRoach Right. I thought `Number` implemented `Comparable`, but of course not. `<T extends Comparable<T>>` is the go.

Comment: @BrianRoach Actually, I've realised that the correct type bound is `<T extends Number & Comparable<T>>` (see answer)

Comment: Er, why would you restrict it only to subclasses of `Number`? There's no reason to do so. The `Comparable<T>` interface guarantees that the things you're putting in the queue are comparable (i.e. they can have priority over one another)

Answer (score 1):

Update below to pass long as

```
  thePQ.insert(30L);
  thePQ.insert(50L);
  thePQ.insert(10L);
  thePQ.insert(40L);
  thePQ.insert(20L);
```